# show Alertview even when App is inactive

Tags: ios, homescreen, alertview

I just saw that it's anyhow possible to show AlertViews from the Background on HomeScreen. [image]

This was triggered by the App "UP by Jawbone"

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I guess this is a system message like about apps that keep using your location in the background

Comment: This message comes from the OS. It was probably triggered by the app asking for accessory connection, which could occur with the app in background. I don't believe there's a way to present a UIAlertView on the springboard from an app in background otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

That's a system message because UP tried to use Bluetooth. It wasn't generated specifically by the app.

Apps cannot display alerts that display when they're in the background. The best you can do is use a Local Notification.

Comment: Ok! Thank you! So I can force this alert to be shown when I try to use Bluetooth in a background task?